# Retrieving value and display from dynamically created edit text

Tags: android

I have a button when I click on that it will display edittext when I enter a value but I am unable to display the entered value for displaying the value I have used textview but I am unable to display.

```
class DynamicbuttonActivity extends Activity {

    TextView view= new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ScrollView scrl=new ScrollView(this);

        final LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrl.addView(ll);

        Button add_btn=new Button(this);
        add_btn.setText("Click to add EditTexts");
        ll.addView(add_btn);

        Button add_btn1=new Button(this);
        add_btn1.setText("Click to view TextViiews");
        ll.addView(add_btn1);

        add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)  { 
                EditText et=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                ll.addView(et);
            }
        });

        add_btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {    
            String strg;
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                strg = et.getText().toString();
                view.setText(strg);
                ll.addView(view);    
            }
        });

        this.setContentView(scrl);
    }  
}
```

Can you please help me ?

Comment: `TextView view = new TextView(getApplicationContext());` not good.  Do the initialization of these in `OnCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation was wrong way. On button click first it will add `EditText` but this you have defined in `onclick` method so you don't getting in another `onclick` method its scope only to the first `onclick` method only

Second thing every time you click on first button it will add EditText in your layout. I didn't understand your definition about this code. I thing definition was when user entered text on `edittext` and click on button that value you want to display in `TextView` then just remove first button and define your `EditText` outside of `onclick` method like as your declare `TextView`

```
public class DynamicbuttonActivity extends Activity {

    TextView view= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    EditText et=new EditText(getApplicationContext());

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ScrollView scrl=new ScrollView(this);

        final LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrl.addView(ll);

        /*Button add_btn=new Button(this);
        add_btn.setText("Click to add EditTexts");
        ll.addView(add_btn);*/
        Button add_btn1=new Button(this);
        add_btn1.setText("Click to view TextViiews");
        ll.addView(add_btn1);
        /*add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){ 
            }

        });*/

        add_btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            String strg;
            public void onClick(View v){
                strg = et.getText().toString();
                view.setText(strg);
            }

        });
        ll.addView(et);
        ll.addView(view);
        this.setContentView(scrl);

    }

}
```

Comment: then how can i display values that i have entered in edittext